# What's the meaning of 'take' in "to take a wide variety of forms"

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of 'take' in "to take a wide variety of forms"?

Does it simply mean 'to have', or maybe 'to include'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To take form* means *to come to have [a] form*.

[Merriam-Webster "take form"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20form)

> to begin to develop : to start to exist or be seen
> *a political movement that first took form in the 1960s*
> *The new stadium is gradually taking form.*

In your example, it may mean about the same as "have", but no context is supplied.

The OP's comment supplies this context:
"... doctors sometimes prescribe hormonal treatments, which take a wide variety of forms."

In that example, "take" is equivalent to "have", because the treatments are all established things.